# Is there an easier way to create a df out of this information?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, readability

I have information that is stored in multiple layers json format which I want to convert to a pandas dataframe, so far I've been doing it this way and I'm sure there is a far more readable solution

At the moment Im just creating empty lists and filling them up by appending each wanted item

the calls and puts variables are dataframes and selected_expiration filters those dataframes:

```
    contract_symbols = []
    strikes = []
    option_types = []
    days_to_expiration = []
    bids = []
    asks = []
    deltas = []
    thetas = []
    vegas = []
    gammas = []
    is_itm = []
    open_interests = []
    theo_values = []
    time_values = []
    volumes = []
    volatilities = []
    descriptions = []

    for strike in calls[selected_expiration]:
        contract_symbols.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['symbol'])
        strikes.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['strikePrice'])
        option_types.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['putCall'])
        days_to_expiration.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['daysToExpiration'])
        bids.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['bid'])
        asks.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['ask'])
        deltas.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['delta'])
        thetas.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['theta'])
        vegas.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['vega'])
        gammas.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['gamma'])
        is_itm.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['inTheMoney'])
        open_interests.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['openInterest'])
        theo_values.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['theoreticalOptionValue'])
        time_values.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['timeValue'])
        volumes.append(calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['totalVolume'])
        volatilities.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['volatility'])
        descriptions.append(
            calls[selected_expiration][strike][0]['description'])

    for strike in puts[selected_expiration]:
        contract_symbols.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['symbol'])
        strikes.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['strikePrice'])
        option_types.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['putCall'])
        days_to_expiration.append(
            puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['daysToExpiration'])
        bids.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['bid'])
        asks.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['ask'])
        deltas.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['delta'])
        thetas.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['theta'])
        vegas.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['vega'])
        gammas.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['gamma'])
        is_itm.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['inTheMoney'])
        open_interests.append(
            puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['openInterest'])
        theo_values.append(
            puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['theoreticalOptionValue'])
        time_values.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['timeValue'])
        volumes.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['totalVolume'])
        volatilities.append(puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['volatility'])
        descriptions.append(
            puts[selected_expiration][strike][0]['description'])

    data = {
        'symbol': contract_symbols,
        'strikePrice': strikes,
        'putCall': option_types,
        'daysToExpiration': days_to_expiration,
        'bid': bids,
        'ask': asks,
        'delta': deltas,
        'theta': thetas,
        'vega': vegas,
        'gamma': gammas,
        'inTheMoney': is_itm,
        'openInterest': open_interests,
        'theo_valuesreticalOptionValue': theo_values,
        'timeValue': time_values,
        'totalVolume': volumes,
        'volatility': volatilities,
        'description': descriptions,
    }

    chain = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: can u add your json file that u wanna read in df?

Comment: hi I have uploaded an example of those datafrfames here: https://github.com/Quaniful/Pub

Comment: sorry I uploaded the jsons*

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the JSON file for calls from GitHub, and did a small amount of parsing.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

filename = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Quaniful/Pub/master/C.json'

field_types = {
    'symbol'                 : 'string',
    'strikePrice'            : 'float',
    'putCall'                : 'string',
    'daysToExpiration'       : 'int',
    'bid'                    : 'float',
    'ask'                    : 'float',
    'delta'                  : 'float',
    'theta'                  : 'float',
    'vega'                   : 'float',
    'gamma'                  : 'float',
    'inTheMoney'             : 'boolean',
    'openInterest'           : 'int',
    'theoreticalOptionValue' : 'float',
    'timeValue'              : 'float',
    'totalVolume'            : 'int',
    'volatility'             : 'float',
    'description'            : 'string',
}
```

Now, the set-up work is done.  Let's retrieve the data:

```
r = requests.get(filename)

ts = list()

# convert JSON response to list of tuples
ts = list()
for strike, ds in r.json().items():
    for d in ds:
        for key, value in d.items():
            t = (float(strike), key, value)
            ts.append(t)

# convert the list-of-tuples to a data frame; rename, and re-shape
calls = (pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=['strike', 'field', 'value'])
         .set_index(['strike', 'field'])
         .sort_index()
         .squeeze()
         .unstack(level='field')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .filter(field_types.keys())
         .astype(field_types, errors='raise')
        )
```

Now, look at the first row (transposed to fit on screen):

```
print(calls.iloc[0])

field
symbol                                      AAPL_080720C455
strikePrice                                             455
putCall                                                CALL
daysToExpiration                                          1
bid                                                    1.91
ask                                                    1.93
delta                                                  0.32
theta                                                -0.832
vega                                                  0.119
gamma                                                 0.038
inTheMoney                                            False
openInterest                                           7959
theoreticalOptionValue                                 1.92
timeValue                                              1.93
totalVolume                                           48222
volatility                                           28.018
description               AAPL Aug 7 2020 455 Call (Weekly)
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I could not figure out a set of parameters in `pd.read_json()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, is it possible to do it without having the price/field indexes? and to filter by these columns? `cols = ['symbol',
        'strikePrice',
        'putCall',
        'daysToExpiration',
        'bid',
        'ask',
        'delta',
        'theta',
        'vega',
        'gamma',
        'inTheMoney',
        'openInterest',
        'theoreticalOptionValue',
        'timeValue',
        'totalVolume',
        'volatility',
        'description']`

Comment: this is how its supposed to look like: `symbol  strikePrice putCall  daysToExpiration   bid   ask  delta  theta   vega  gamma  inTheMoney  openInterest  theo_valuesreticalOptionValue  timeValue  totalVolume  volatility                         description
0     AAPL_080720C460        460.0    CALL                 0  1.73  1.93  0.255 -1.946  0.076  0.026       False         13241                          1.830       1.85        88480      51.380   AAPL Aug 7 2020 460 Call (Weekly)`

Comment: I updated the response to include specified columns.  If this was useful, please consider accepting this response.